# c# how to play shoting audio And make it can hear publick not local only

Tags: unity-game-engine

how to play audio on a specific location? I did but My audio can hear by me only, can't hear by other players, here is my code

```
public AudioClip shotaudio;
public void Awake()
{
 this.shotaudio= new WWW("file://" + Application.dataPath + "/Resources/Sound/Shot.wav").GetAudioClip(true);

}

public void Shot()
{
AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(this.shotaudio, main_Object.transform.position;
}
```

the problem is, the sound only can hear by me, anyone can help me how to make shots audio public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, what I understand is that this is a multiplayer online game and if one player shoot only the shooter can hear the audio.

If my understanding is correct you can do the following:
1. Send shoot event or protocol in your "shot" function to server with playerID and shoot position.
2. When your server get the protocol, send the event to any other player in the same game with shoot position. 
3. You need add new function to listen the server message. When you get the shoot event by server, call the Shot function right now.